# Does the code below use command pattern

Tags: java

I have a very basic question about the command pattern. Supose, I have an interface like

```
public interface Task {  
    public void execute();  
}
```

and some class implementing the interface Task

```
class SomeClass implements Task {  
public void execute() {  
 //do something  
}  


class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
         Task task = new SomeClass();  
          task.execute();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, it uses command pattern.

Comment: Looks like Command pattern to me....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the command pattern.  See more information here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Java

Replace the `Command` interface in the example with your `Task` interface, and you can see how this is like a `Command`.